# Smart contract interaction from front-end issue

Tags: reactjs, solidity

Any help will be much appreciated:

Am building the front end for my smart contract. Was able not only to receive data but also to send data to the smart contract from front-end.

**The way I called  data from my smart contract:**

*Solidity function:*   `function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) { return address(this).balance; }`

*My front-end code to call the above function:*

```
const getBalance = async () => {
    setBalance((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      loading: true,
    }))
    info.contract.methods
      .getBalance()
      .call()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        setBalance({
          loading: false,
          value: res,
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        setBalance(initBalanceState)
      })
  }
```

**The way I sent data to my smart contract**

*Solidity code:*

```
function plantSeeds(address ref) public payable {
        require(initialized);
        uint256 seedsBought = calculateSeedBuy(msg.value,SafeMath.sub(address(this).balance,msg.value));
        seedsBought = SafeMath.sub(seedsBought,devFee(seedsBought));
        uint256 fee = devFee(msg.value);
        recAddr.transfer(fee);
        claimedSeeds[msg.sender] = SafeMath.add(claimedSeeds[msg.sender],seedsBought);
        replantSeeds(ref);
    }
```

*My front-end code to send eth to the above function:*

```
const plantSeeds = () => {
    let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
    info.contract.methods
      .plantSeeds(ref)
      .send({
        from: info.account,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(num, 'ether'),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        
      })
  }
```

So, I was able to read data and send data to the smart contract without problem. BUT, How do you call a withdrawable function? I need to send funds from Smart contract to the wallet. from etherscan/write section can do it, it's working, but how to do it from website front end? Any help?

here is the solidity code am trying to initiate from the front-end:

```
function harvestSeeds() public {
        require(initialized);
        uint256 hasSeeds = getMySeeds(msg.sender);
        uint256 seedValue = calculateSeedSell(hasSeeds);
        uint256 fee = devFee(seedValue);
        claimedSeeds[msg.sender] = 0;
        lastPlanted[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        marketSeeds = SafeMath.add(marketSeeds,hasSeeds);
        recAddr.transfer(fee);
        payable (msg.sender).transfer(SafeMath.sub(seedValue,fee));
    }
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just call it like you reading data from the smartcontract and it will work